# Has automatic all-seat reclining been tested?

Tags: aircraft-design, seats

Seat reclining in modern economy-class seats is a problem when person in front of you reclines, but you are still in vertical position.

Has there been a consideration of simultaneous reclining of **all** the seats at the same time right after take-off?

Comment: I sure hope not. That would be awful. Can you imagine trying to read, or use a laptop?

Comment: I thought they were going out of their way to create a miserable experience.  The only way to make this worse would be to randomly move the seatbacks up at random intervals and speeds.

Comment: The _only_ way? The low-cost airlines seem to be very creative in making a bad experience worse!

Comment: I can't imagine a manufacturer trying that for medical liability reasons; someone's back might be screwed up.

Comment: Your proposal would add several tons of weight to the aircraft by motorizing all the seats.

Comment: @Hobbes nah, just a latch that's released using a spring loaded mechanism. Seat drops back instantly, problem solved. Of course to put them up again someone'd have to go and recock the mechanism in each seat by hand :)

Comment: I'd much rather they remove the option to recline the seats at all. Problem solved, no more people slamming their seat back into your knees or chin. And all it'd take is a few spot welds :)

Comment: Some mobility impaired people may be very uncomfortable in the reclined position.